# Show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{ln}(n)}{n^x}$ is not uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Show $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{ln}(n)}{n^x}$ is not uniformly convergent on $(1,\infty)$.

I thought I can show that $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in (1,\infty)}\left|\frac{\mathrm{ln}(n)}{n^x}\right|\not\to 0$, but it does, so this doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that the series diverges at $x = 1$. Rewrite the series as

$$f(x) := \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{e^{x \ln n}}$$

So the error term can be expressed as

$$\left|f(x) - \sum_{n = 1}^{N - 1} \frac{\ln n}{e^{x \ln n}}\right| = \sum_{n = N}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{e^{x \ln n}} > \frac{\ln N}{e^{x \ln N}}$$

Now if $x \approx 1$, the denominator is very small, while the numerator is very large; for example, if $N$ is chosen so that $\ln N = 1 / x$, the error is $\ln N$. You can use this to finish the proof.

Comment: For a different interpretation, $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on $\{z : \Re z > 1\}$; we cannot extend $f$ holomorphically across $z = 1$ because it would have a pole there.

Comment: I'm not quite see the end, I'm having trouble with that. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Stabilo Can you ask something more specific? You suppose uniform convergence works, choose $\epsilon > 0$ and $N$ so that the definition holds, and then choose $x$ near $1/\ln N$ to contradict things.

Comment: So it's greater than $lnN/e$? So the partial sums series does not converge? So how rewriting the series helped in fact?

Comment: @Stabilo The partial sums do converge; the point is that the rate of convergence (that is, the choice of $N$ depending on $\epsilon$ to make the error from $N$ terms less than $\epsilon$) varies depending on $x$. If $x$ is very small, then we need very many terms to have a small error.

Comment: But if the partial sums sequence converges so does the series. Isn't it?

Comment: @Stabilo Yes, the series is convergent.

Comment: So this proves that the partial sums sequence is not uniformly convergent so the series isn't uniformly convergent?

Comment: Yes, the sequence of partial sums is convergent but not uniformly convergent.